# Where can I find a smart contract code for an ICO?

Tags: ico

Since the creation of tokens is a standardized process following the ERC20 specifications, I want to know if there is also a "common code" or a default way to create a crowdsale for an ICO

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenZeppelin has a GitHub repo with peer-reviewed open source contracts for tokens and crowdsales. They're a good source to see working ICO contracts.

The examples include refundable crowdsales, capped crowdsales, finalizable crowdsales, and different types of ERC20 token contracts.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts

Comment: See the OpenZeppelin Contracts documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts

Answer (score 2):

There's no real standard for token sales, but I published a walkthrough of a typical approach on my blog last week: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/02/writing-a-token-sale-contract/.

Comment: Good blog post, helped me to understand the basis.